# What's the standard BPMN Process design practice when we spwan multiple sub process and manage them?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, process, bpmn, business-rules

I'm trying to design a process which will spawn multiple sub process(instances) and finally the outcome of the sub-processes will decide the main process flow.

As I agree there can by multiple ways to design the same, but wanted to to check from all experts in this forum.

My query is what is the followed model in this case. 
Do we create two individual processes - 
          1. to spawn the process and then wrap it up.
          2. To keep track the sub processes and inform the main process(1).

Please help me with your suggestions.

Thanks & regards,
BPMN developer.

Comment: What is the criterion for starting/stopping sub-processes? The phrase *the outcome of the sub-processes will decide the main process flow* is totally unclear.

Answer (score 0):

For this use case, BPMN has `multi-instanc Activities` - see the [BPMN Specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF/), page 432 (page 462 in PDF).

You can create a sub process of the type `multi-instance Activity` and define - via the `isSequential` attribute - whether the sub processes should be spawned sequentially or in parallel.

Via the `completionCondition Expression`, you can define a check that is executed every time an instance completes and that cancels all other instances if it returns `true`.

Comment: Thanks mate! for the wonderful suggestion.
I have started implementing it and will keep you posted how it goes.